# Changing dns to OpenDns works only in the current session, not for my child and not after reboot

Tags: networking, 16.04, dns, opendns

I configured OpenDns as suggested [here](https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/228007087-Ubuntu-OpenDNS-Device-Configuration) (even the final part)
It works immediately after the changes, BUT:

1. If I switch to the user of my child, it doesn't work anymore
2. If I switch back to my account it doesn't work anymore

If I look at the configuration after the switch and after the restart, everything is there as when I configured it having it working.
So... I am a little bit confused about how it works the first time and then not anymore.

EDIT 2023-12-04: actually I realised that the Ubuntu version was too old (16.04 LTS).
I decided to upgrade release to the last one 22.04 LTS even if that laptop is really old (Pentium).
The issue is not present anymore (and the performance are still very very good)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using at least 22.04 and systemd.

edit the file /etc/systemd/resolved.conf

```
DNS=208.67.222.222#resolver4.opendns.com 208.67.220.220#resolver2.opendns.com
```

or run the below sed command as root:

```
sed -i 's/^DNS=.*/DNS=208.67.222.222#resolver4.opendns.com 208.67.220.220#resolver2.opendns.com/' /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
```

That will set OpenDNS as your global DNS and will be persistent across reboots.

Comment: Thanks Luke, actually I was using a very old Ubuntu version. Editing the question.

Comment: In that case, just edit the /etc/resolv.conf file directly, and add nameserver <ip> twice, once for each server.  and you should be right